# How to explorer properties and methods of an object in Kademi EDM template

Tags: html-email, kademi

I have a question related to Kademi platform. In normal page templating, I can use `#docs` for exploring properties and methods of an object but in EDM template, I can not. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use #docs in theme/emailBase.html

Variables specific to automation are copied into the templating model for the base template, so can be referenced from $page.model.xxx, where xxx is the same variable name as in the automation template

For example, if you're writing an automation template for an event, and you're not sure what the event is and what properties it has, use this;

```
#docs($page.model.event)
```